# Is there any way for using UrlLink within a table in pdf Dart package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I have a one column table working in my app but I want to include hyperlinks within the text of the table. Is there any way of doing it?

This is my code for data generation:

```
data: List<List<String>>.generate(
  widget.data.length,
  (row) => List<String>.generate(
    1,
    (col) => widget.data[row].infoReport + "\n\n" + widget.data[row].report
  )
)
```

And I want for example "widget.data[row].report" being a link.

Thanks in advance.